# Handling timeouts during gcloud sql instance creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm using `gcloud sql instances create` to create CloudSQL instances. More often than not, that command times out, but provides a command to wait until databse creation is done.

```
$ gcloud sql instances create mydb
Creating Cloud SQL instance...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.create) Operation https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/foobar/operations/abcd is taking longer than expected. 
You can continue waiting for the operation by running `gcloud sql operations wait --project foobar abcd`
$ gcloud sql operations wait --project foobar abcd
Waiting for [https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/foobar/operations/abcd]...done.
NAME  TYPE    START                          END                            ERROR  STATUS
abcd  CREATE  2018-03-19T15:04:29.477+00:00  2018-03-19T15:10:08.561+00:00  -      DONE
```

I wonder if it's possible to configure the timeout for `gcloud sql instances create`? I can't seem to find anything in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/create), not even the timeout it's using by default.

Another option would be to start instance creation asynchronously, list the pending operations and wait for their completion:

```
$ gcloud sql instances create mydb --async
$ PENDING_OPERATIONS=$(gcloud sql operations list --instance=mydb --filter='status!=DONE' --format='value(name)')
$ gcloud sql operations wait "${PENDING_OPERATIONS}"
```

But then again, would `gcloud sql operations wait` timeout at some point? The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/operations/wait) don't mention any timeout either.

Comment: I went through the docs and can't find a timeout either. Mind you, the timeout won't affect whether an operation goes through or not.
I'm also curious why your operation is timing out, gcloud sql instances create is a pretty simply operation and shouldn't take long to complete

Comment: Where are you running the command from? Can you try running the same command from the Cloud shell or another system?

Comment: @PatrickW I created 4 instances yesterday, and hit the timeout 3 times. I'm running the command from my workstation in Germany to create instances in region europe-west1. I haven't tried running it from Cloud shell, because the "create instance" command is just one part of a script and the timeout isn't a big issue.

Comment: I just bumped into this error and issued the 'wait' command.  It timed out a second time and prompted me again to issue the 'wait' command.  Perhaps this is the wrong place for a rant, but WTF?  This is amateurish at best.  Succeed quietly, fail loudly....don't issue a message that says "ERROR" about an operation that hasn't even completed!  This is just pure madness on Google's part.

Answer (score 1):

I think it times out because I'm creating the MySQL instance on the smallest machine available: db-f1-micro
which is enough for my dev platform.

I've tried several options to capture the command output and run the suggested command, but can't find a way to get it.
It's as if the output was printed on something else that stderr or stdout.

I've tried the following :

```
MyVAR=$($COMMAND)
$COMMAND | tee command.log
$COMMAND 2>&1 > command.log
```

if we could capture the output of the command, then my script bellow would work.

```
gcloud sql instances create ${MYSQL_INSTANCE}    \
        --assign-ip                              \
        ${BACKUP}                                \
        ${BACKUP_START_TIME}                     \
        ${BACKUP_ENABLE_BIN_LOG}                 \
        --database-flags=${MYSQL_FLAGS}          \
        --database-version=${MYSQL_DB_VERSION}   \
        --gce-zone=${MYSQL_ZONE}                 \
        --maintenance-release-channel=production \
        --maintenance-window-day=MON             \
        --maintenance-window-hour=4              \
        --pricing-plan=PER_USE                   \
        --storage-auto-increase                  \
        --storage-size=${MYSQL_STORAGE}          \
        --storage-type=${MYSQL_STORAGE_TYPE}     \
        --tier=${MYSQL_TIER}                     \
        --format=json                            | tee logs/${COUNTRY}-${ENV}.log

GCLOUD_CREATE_INSTANCE_RETURN_CODE=$?

if [ ${GCLOUD_CREATE_INSTANCE_RETURN_CODE} -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully created DB"
else
  echo "Error returned while creating the DB"

  TIMEOUT_ERROR=$(cat logs/${COUNTRY}-${ENV}.log | tail -1 | grep "gcloud beta sql operations wait" | wc -l)

  if [ "${TIMEOUT_ERROR}" = "1" ]
  then
    echo "It's a timeout error, continue waiting"
    FOLLOW_UP_COMMAND=$(cat logs/${COUNTRY}-${ENV}.log | tail -1 |cut -d '`' -f2)
    ${FOLLOW_UP_COMMAND}
  else
    echo "It's NOT a timeout error"
    echo "return code : ${GCLOUD_CREATE_INSTANCE_RETURN_CODE}"
    echo  ${GCLOUD_CREATE_INSTANCE_OUTPUT}
    exit 1
  fi
fi
```

gcloud sql users set-password root --instance=${MYSQL_INSTANCE} --password=${MYSQL_ROOT} --host "%"

In the end, I ended up putting a big sleep after the create instance command so that I can set the root password.

for db-f1-micro it took 2min53sec more to complete the creation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `--timeout` flag in the `wait` command (not sure if it's a recent addition). The default is 300s.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/operations/wait

So you can do `gcloud sql operations wait "${PENDING_OPERATIONS}" --timeout=unlimited`